# [Itemdescriptor-name]There is some error- in console

Tags: repository, atg, atg-dynamo

In the below code to get values from repository from form handler ,I am not getting any output[All mapings are correct]..

```
 public void handleSearch(DynamoHttpServletRequest req,DynamoHttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException, RepositoryException{
    try{
                RepositoryView view=getProfileValue().getView("onetomanyarray");
                RqlStatement statement=RqlStatement.parseRqlStatement("Uage like ?0");

                //while using integers for retrieval I used following code
                 Object params[] = new Object[1];
                   params[0] = new Integer(25);

                //for string I am using  
                Object params[] ={new String("sud")};



                RepositoryItem [] items=statement.executeQuery(view, params);




            }catch (RepositoryException rpe){
                logError("There is Some Error");
            }
```

In the above sample class code when I hit the submit button ,no changes in JSP Page  but in the console I get Error in Item descriptor name[both for integer and string].
NOTE:onetomanyarray Is the name of Item Descriptor

Comment: You need to provide more information. Does `getProfileView()` return a Repository? Is it the right repository? Does it define an item descriptor called `onetomanyarray`? Descriptor names are case sensitive. Also, what is the exact error you are getting? Provide details of the actual RepositoryException

Comment: @Vihung , When I hit submit button , .getProfileView returns "xml" file name,thats it along with message"SQL REPOSITORY STARTUP COMPLETE"

Comment: @sudarshan do you have the same property Uage for different data types  try changing to single data type ?

Comment: @ManojKrishna ,Tried that also,but not working...

Comment: what is the error now you are facing @sudarshan